# «Турнир неслучайно называют куда больше чем просто Кубком Крыма»

Tags: запятые

Верно ли без запятой? Смущает слово «куда». То есть все равно смысл: больше чем просто Кубок Крыма, верно? То есть без запятой?

Comment: "Называют куда больше" как-то странно звучит, по крайней мере на мой взгляд. In my opinion, it's at least a garden-path sentence.

Comment: уберу «куда больше»....

Comment: Уваж. flossyU, Повтор (дублирование) темы и текста в вопросах, разумеется, не запрещено. Какой  в этом смысл или польза?

Comment: мне удобно так, как я пишу....

Comment: Приятно, когда людям удобно. Особенно, если два раза удобно. Умение копировать — не умение писать.

Comment: я не понимаю, в чем проблема....

Comment: Много одинаковых фраз.

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, здесь ссылаются на то, что часто можно услышать такое: "*этот турнир куда больше, чем просто кубок Крыма!*" Эмоционально окрашенное "куда" (гораздо, намного) должно относиться не к речи автора, а к условно цитируемому ходовому выражению по поводу этого кубка. Для этого нужно разграничить авторскую речь с той, на которую ссылаются, - это можно сделать кавычками. Официальное название турнира ("Кубок" с заглавной буквы) не вполне сочетается с эпитетом "просто", естественнее написать "кубок" со строчной буквы (подразумевается: это не просто кубок Крыма - это **К**убок Крыма!). Предлагаемый вариант:

> Турнир не случайно называют "куда больше, чем просто кубком Крыма".

"Не случайно" здесь написано раздельно на приводимом у Розенталя основании: http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2324

Comment: Не понял, Александр, а зачем конец цитаты в кавычках?

Answer (score 0):

```
То есть все равно смысл: больше чем просто Кубок Крыма, верно? То есть без запятой?
```

То есть именно с запятой.

Comment: больше чем Кубок мира...здесь ничего не сравнивается...